# Git authenticate using unknown method to my bitbucket

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

All similar topic to mine trying to explain how to configure git to be able to use bitbucket/github.
My topic is regarding different stroy.
I'm able to push/clone/commit - do whatever I want to my repository on bitbucket, but:

1) My repository does not have any "Access keys" in settings

2) My git config:

```
user.name=No Matter
user.email=anybody@fromanywhere.com
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=ssh://git@bitbucket.XXXX:7999/~someuser/test.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.preprod.remote=origin
branch.preprod.merge=refs/heads/preprod
```

When I'm trying to findout which SSH key is used I read many topic on stackoverflow that I should use "ssh -vT git@bitbucket.XXX" but finally it ask me for a password.

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /someuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /someuser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /someuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /someuser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@bitbucket.XXXX's password:
```

How to find out which method/ssh key is git using when I'm using commands such as: git pull;git push?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the port in your command - otherwise `ssh` will assume you're trying port 22. (There is something listening at bitbucket.XXXX:22 but it isn't your Bitbucket Server instance - it's probably sshd on the host operating system.)

Try something like `ssh -Tp7999 git@bitbucket.XXXX` instead. The `-p` flag lets you specify a nonstandard port for SSH - in this case, based on your git config, it's port 7999. You can also try `ssh -Tp433 git@altssh.bitbucket.org` for an example with Bitbucket Cloud.

Comment: @Jim_Redmond specifying the port showed me which key is used to authenticate! But the next quesiton is how to check which key is used to specified repository instead of whole domain. My repo has empty "Access Keys" tab where I should put ssh keys.

Comment: Are there keys associated with specific user accounts?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 ssh -v git@bitbucket.com
```

That will give you something like this.

```
OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.com [18.205.93.4] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/sdr/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
```

In that line you can see where is it. Usually they are here `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: I have already mentioned about the output from ssh -v command. It ask me for a password  - so It doesnt use ssh key - and when I'm using git commands to my repo everything works - but why?

Comment: Did you tried writting your password? What happens after? If you need a quick solution, you can also dowload gitKraken, which has automatic ssh gen and connection with every git service

Comment: I don't know password for git user at bitbucket site( I even don't have acces to backend of it). I know only my linux password for my someuser user.